# Passing a jcombobox variable from one class to another class using a jbutton action in another class

Tags: java, mysql, swing

So, in `Java` I have two classes is created using `swing components`.  In one class, named `SearchPage`, I set up parameters for a search in the `Jtextfield` or `Jcombobox` provided and click the apply `jbutton`.  When I do that, depending on what field contains data, I want to send that variable over to the `ItemPage` class to be used in my pop_tree method to use that variable to search my mysql database and populate the tree with the search results.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is the code for the `pop_tree` method:

```
public final void pop_tree() throws SQLException {
    //creating root node
    DefaultTreeModel dbtree = (DefaultTreeModel)DBTree.getModel();
    dbtree.reload();
    dbtree.getRoot();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode content = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Content");

        //let's see if I can create these child nodes
        SearchPage s = new SearchPage();
        try {
            con = DBconnect.getConnection();
            stm = con.createStatement();
            s.apply_search_button.doClick();
            if(s.apply_search_button.getModel().isPressed()){
            //Grab what's in search field of Search Page
            try{
                String search = s.search_field.getText();
                if (search == null){
                    return;
                }else{
                    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * from displaydetails WHERE item LIKE '%"+search+"%'");
                    while (rs.next()){
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode itemNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (rs.getString("item"));
                        content.add(itemNode);
                    }
                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            try{
                //If a genre selection is made in the combo box:
                if ((s.option_box.getSelectedItem())== "genre"){
                String genre2 = s.result_box.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (genre2.equals(s.result_box.getSelectedItem())) {
                    ResultSet rs1 = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * from displaydetails WHERE genre = '" + genre2 + "';");
                    while (rs1.next()){
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode itemNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (rs1.getString("item"));
                        content.add(itemNode);
                    }
                }
            }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

I have the search form created to setup the search parameters, but when I click the `apply_search_button` on the form, I want to send the variable to the proper location in the `pop_tree()` method to perform the search.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks.

Comment: You do it the same way you pass any information from one class to another, either via method parameters or the constructor, depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: Perhaps you should start by having a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do setters and getters.  That approach doesn't seem to work.  Besides, I want to use the variable as a parameter in my mysql state for search.

Comment: So? You "get" information from some source, I assume a dialog of some kind, you use getters to get that information and pass it to your method, I still fail to see why this is such a difficult issue

Comment: Because it hangs the app.  I need to insert the value into the mysql syntax in the statement i.e. ("SELECT * from mydatabase WHERE item = '(this is where the value should go').

Once that happens, when I click the apply button, the jtree changes dynamically to the data returned from the search query.

Comment: If it's hanging the program, this isn't an issue with passing data, but the fact you are calling the method in the context of the EDT.  Maybe have a look at `SwingWorker` for a simply solution to off load the call to a background call, but which provides you with additional functionality to safely update the UI from

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get answer to "Passing a jcombobox variable from one class to another class using a jbutton action in another class" much of the code posted, is not needed. 
Always consider posting [[mcve]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  
Here is one that demonstrates just that :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SearchPage extends JFrame {

    private JTextField searchField;
    private JButton searchButton;
    private ItemPage itemPage;

    SearchPage(){
        setSize(200,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        searchField = new JTextField(9);
        add(searchField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchButton.addActionListener(e -> {

            String searchFor = searchField.getText();
            if ((searchFor != null) && ! searchFor.isEmpty()) {
                itemPage.search(searchFor);
            }
        });
        add(searchButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        itemPage = new ItemPage();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new SearchPage();
    }
}

class ItemPage {

    public void search(String searchFor) {
        System.out.println("Searching for "+ searchFor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I took a couple of things from this and applied them and I'm able to pass the value to a method; however, with my pop_tree() method being non-static, I can't pass the values there, which is where I need them.  Anymore suggestions?

Comment: @VictorCreed Change `pop_tree`

Comment: Hmmm, make pop_tree static?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I appreciate you trying to lead me down the right path.  You might be on to something.  Let me try that. :)

Comment: @VictorCreed I'd change `pop_tree` to accept parameters

Comment: And I did just that.  I think I may have solved it, thanks to your suggestion.  I'm going to try a few things.  I will get back in 20 minutes on whether or not it really worked.

Comment: Well, bubba!  That worked.  I changed pop_tree to accept parameters, reworked the code on the SearchPage and it works...atleast with the genre search, but I'm sure it will work with all the rest.  Thank you so much for leading me down the right path, @MadProgrammer!!!

Comment: That worked for all my search parameters...thanks again.